# Does the decay of $\rho^0$ meson imply that charged pions have non-integer orbital angular momentum?

Tags: particle-physics, angular-momentum, conservation-laws, mesons, pions

In the decay $\rho_0\rightarrow \pi^+ + \pi^-$ the $\rho_0$ has total angular momentum 1 and the $\pi^\pm$ both have spin zero.

In order to conserve total angular momentum, the pions must therefore have a net orbital momentum of 1. Does this mean that charged pions have non-integer orbital angular momentum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two pions are produced in a system with an orbital angular momentum of 1 about each other. Orbital angular momentum is a property of two particles, though for familiar electrons in atoms the partner is the nucleus so it's not mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I didn't specific the total angular momentum of the rho, but you are correct that it is 1